# Pushing data from one Sheets to another at regular time intervals

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I came across a Sheets that automatically pushes data to another Sheets every 1 month. I only have view access to the Sheets and am curious to know whether the scheduling involves a script.

The Sheets indicates the following info:

- Last pushed on 17 Mar 2022 08:10:56 +0800
- Scheduled to run automatically every 1 month

Can anyone point me to relevant websites to learn more about this? I tried Googling but only found information related to Sheets functions like importdata and importrange.

I'm also wondering what are the potential benefits of scheduling the Sheets to pull data at regular intervals, rather than using the importrange function that syncs data in real time.

Comment: Hi! I think that ```IMPORTRANGE()``` is useful when you don't need to manipulate/modify  the data along the way. Otherwise, [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) should be used. A javascript based script is written and you'd have to set an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) at the frequency fof your choice.

Comment: Thanks so much @santosOnit! Google Apps Script is new to me and sounds like a powerful tool to explore :))